# Dynamic Column Laravel Datatable Serverside

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I have table structure like this picture
[image: Table Design]
each events has a different form template, and participants can fill it out based on that form template and save it in the submissions content with json format.

How to make laravel datatable with dynamic column every time enter the event page, which means in one event it has the same column.

This is my serverside code:

```
public function datatable(Request $request, $id)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        
        $models = Submission::whereHas('event.forms', function($q) use($id){
            $q->where('code', $id);
        });

        return DataTables::of($models)

            ->addColumn('action',  function($model){
                return 'button action';
            })

            // HERE DYNAMIC COLUMN THAT I WANT

            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->escapeColumns([])
            ->rawColumns([''])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

This is my jquery code:

```
var datas_datatable = $('#datas_datatable').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
            ],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    text: 'Column',
                },
                'pageLength',
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible th:not(:last-child)'
                    }
                },
                "{{ auth()->user()->isAbleTo('events-create') }} " == 1 ? {
                    text: 'Tambah',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                        add("{{ route('getform_events') }}");
                    }
                } : {}
            ],
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            ajax: url,
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
                // HERE DYNAMIC COLUMN THAT I WANT
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    className: "action-center"
                },
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {   
                    "targets": [],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": true
                }
            ],
            order: [
                [0, "asc"]
            ],
        });
```

This is table header table:

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="datas_datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        @foreach ($template->forms as $item)
                            <th>{{ $item->title }}</th>
                        @endforeach
                        <th>Aksi</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
    </div>
```

And this is json content:

> [
> {
> "name": "xer4D120nDtEbzhgnIjGKqVfY",
> "value": "199605042022031001"
> },
> {
> "name": "HWo18g74sz3FhxuwoY6RE8NH8",
> "value": "Kevin"
> },
> {
> "name": "MqEfBRVgCcdtilf5BUYL7g8qW",
> "value": "asasfasf"
> }
> ]

Answer (score 0):

```
public function datatable(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            
            $models = Submission::whereHas('event.forms', function($q) use($id){
                $q->where('code', $id);
            });
    
            $dt = DataTables::of($models)
    
                ->addColumn('action',  function($model){
                    return 'button action';
                });
    
                // SAMPLE 

                $dt->addColumn('sample', function($row){
                  return 'sample value '.$row->id;
                });

    
    
    
                $dt->addIndexColumn()
                ->escapeColumns([])
                ->rawColumns([''])
                ->make(true);
                return $dt;
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation with your answer so that OP can understand what changes were required to meet his requirement or resolve his problem?